# Ion Auth Codeigniter - Default User/Password Not recognised

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I'm new to Codeigniter and Ion Auth. Installed everything OK and set up the ION Auth DB tables. Go to BASE_URL/index.php/auth and I got an error about using encryption. So, I edited that in config by adding a simple string for now.

So, now I can see the login form - good! But when I use the default user and password, I'm getting incorrect password validation...which suggests there is something wrong.

Any ideas why this would be failing? I'm using admin@admin.com and password, as indicated on the Ion Auth pages http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what changes did u make in ion_auth config?

Comment: @Arunu Nothing that I remember...the config changes I made were for encryption in the CI config file `$config['encryption_key'] = 'GarethsKey';`. Can't figure it out, think I might need to go for a fresh install and see if it works with nothing else going on, then work backwards. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I made an error when running the SQL scripts - I simply created the table structure but didn't load the seed data, which includes the default username and password. D'oh! So, if anyone else is having the same issue...just make sure you have data in your tables.